# Pass params to function using on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(document).on('click', '#my', myFunc('param'));

function myFunc(param){
    //do something
}
```

is this snytax wrong? I got error of `jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: ((x.event.special[i.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || i.handler).apply is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send data object as third parameter for `on()` like below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my', {p: 'World'}, myFunc);
```

and in the function, you can access the data object using `event.data` when the event is triggred like below:

```
function myFunc(event) {
  console.log('Hello, ' + event.data.p);
}
```

See this page at section `Passing data to the handler`: http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data

Answer (score 1):

You are not binding the myFunc with a certain parameter but instead are calling the function myFunc('param') and are binding the result of that method call.

One way to do what you want is wrapping your call inside another function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my', function() { myFunc('param') });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed wrong. 'on' callback expects [http://api.jquery.com/on/] an event as first parameter. In it's current form, your code has no chance to work since myFunc('param') is not a function (it's the result of it's evaluation).

You can simply wrap your inner function this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my', function() { myFunc('param'); });

function myFunc(param){
    //do something
}
```

but if you want to properly use jquery in that handler, you need to bind this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my', function() { myFunc.bind(this)('param'); });

    function myFunc(param){
        //do something
    }
```

You could also make your function return another function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my', myFunc('param') );

    function myFunc(param){
         return function() {
         };
    }
```

Here is a complete fiddle

```js
function myFunc1(p) {
  return function() {
    $(this)[0].innerHTML = "modified by " + p;
  };
}

function myFunc2(p) {
    $(this)[0].innerHTML = "modified by " + p;
}

$(document).on("click", "#one", myFunc1("inner wrapping"));
$(document).on("click", "#two", function() { myFunc2.bind(this)("outer wrapping");});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
```

Comment: Any reason you're `return`ing `myFunc`?

Comment: indeed none. Editing

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#my', myFunc('param'); );` won't work.

Comment: it does. look at the fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ufmk2zsj/1/ look in the console. An error 1) Because that extraneous semi-colon 2) You're calling the function immediately instead of passing a reference to it or calling it within a callback.

Comment: damn. because of the semicolon. how useful. Please point the typo directly

Comment: [Load this with the console open](https://jsfiddle.net/ufmk2zsj/3/). The function is called without the button being clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112257/discussion-between-regis-portalez-and-andy).

Comment: I can't. Sorry. Working.